# celery: could not connect to rabbitmq

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

Using rabbitmq as broker for celery. Issue is coming while running command

```
celery -A proj worker   --loglevel=info
```

celery console shows this

```
[2017-06-23 07:57:09,261: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://bruce:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: timed out.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...

[2017-06-23 07:57:15,285: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://bruce:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: timed out.
Trying again in 4.00 seconds...
```

following are the logs from rabbitmq

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 23-Jun-2017::13:28:58 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.18756.0> (127.0.0.1:58424 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
{handshake_timeout,frame_header}

=INFO REPORT==== 23-Jun-2017::13:29:04 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.18897.0> (127.0.0.1:58425 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 23-Jun-2017::13:29:14 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.18897.0> (127.0.0.1:58425 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
{handshake_timeout,frame_header}

=INFO REPORT==== 23-Jun-2017::13:29:22 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.19054.0> (127.0.0.1:58426 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: check if `rabbitmqctl status` shows that node is running or not

Comment: Check whether your `RabbitMq` server is running. If not,  you can run it using: `rabbitmq-server`.

Answer (score 2):

I know its late

But I came across the same issue  today, spent almost an hour to find the exact fix. Thought it might help someone else

I was using celery version 4.1.0

Hope you have configured RabbitMQ properly, if not please configure it as mentioned in the page http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html#setting-up-rabbitmq

Also cross check if the broker url is correct. Here is the brocker url syntax
amqp://**user_name**:**password**@**localhost**/**host_name**

You might not need  to specify the port number, since it will automatically select the default one

If you follow the same variables from the setup tutorial link above your Brocker url will be like
**amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost/myvhost**

Follow this project structure

```
Project
  ../app
  ../Project
     ../settings.py
     ../celery.py
     ../tasks.py
     ../celery_config.py
```

**celery_config.py**

```
# - - - - - - - - - -
# BROKER SETTINGS
# - - - - - - - - - -
# BROKER_URL = os.environ['APP_BROKER_URL']
BROKER_HEARTBEAT = 10
BROKER_HEARTBEAT_CHECKRATE = 2.0

# Setting BROKER_POOL_LIMIT to None disables pooling
# Disabling pooling causes open/close connections for every task.
# However, the rabbitMQ cluster being behind an Elastic Load Balancer,
# the pooling is not working correctly,
# and the connection is lost at some point.
# There seems no other way around it for the time being.
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = None

BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'confirm_publish': True}

BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 20
BROKER_CONNECTION_RETRY = True
BROKER_CONNECTION_MAX_RETRIES = 100
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

from Project import celery_config

app = Celery('Project',
            broker='amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost/myvhost',
            backend='amqp://',
            include=['Project'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
# app.conf.update(
#     result_expires=3600,
#     CELERY_BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = None,
# )

app.config_from_object(celery_config)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

**tasks.py**

```
 from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
 from .celery import app


 @app.task
 def add(x, y):
      return x + y
```

Then start the celery with **“celery -A Project worker -l info”** from the project directory

Everything will be fine.

Comment: celery 4.1 document URL on configuring rabbitmq is changed to:
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/v4.1.0/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html

Answer (score 0):

set CELERY_BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = None in settings.py

Comment: Doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for GCP users.

I've been working on GCP and faced the same issue.

The error message was :

> [2022-03-15 16:56:00,318: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect
> to amqp://root:**@34.125.161.132:5672/vhost: timed out.

I spent almost one hour to solve this issue and finally found the solution

We have to add the port number `5672` in the `Firewall` rules

Steps:

1. Go to Firewall
2. select default-allow-http rule
3. press Edit
4. search "Specified protocols and ports"
5. add 5672 in tcp box ( example if you want to add more ports : 80,5672,8000 )

save the changes and there you go !